# Qt project file: Multiple platforms with debug and release

Tags: c++, qt

With my project, I'd like to support Windows (vc12) and Linux (gcc). The problem is that there are different paths and libraries for each build mode.

```
#shared all
unix
{
# unix shared
 debug
 {
  # unix debug
 }
 release
 {
  # unix release
 }
}
win32
{
 # win shared
 debug
 {
  # win debug
 }
 release
 {
  # win release
 }
}
```

My experience so far, that the unix/win32 works, but the debug/release is not.
Is there a way to achive this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
   #code for release mode
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
   #code for debug mode
}
```